# Take all free space between elements in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I need layout with three elements:

1. `TextView1` with fixed width
2. `TextView2` with dynamic width
3. One more `TextView3` with fixed width

All elements must be visible on the screen at the same time.

If `TextView2` contains a lot of text, the layout should be like this:

[image]

If `TextView2` contains contains little text, the layout should be like this:
[image: little]

How can I create it using `ConstraintLayout` ?

Comment: do you want them to be right side on the screen or center

Comment: The elements should be aligned to the right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `TextViews` in a horitzontal packed chain with a bias of `1` to align them to parent's `end`. To make sure that the middle `TextView` doesn't overlap other `Views` and satisfies its constraints you need to set `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` attribute for it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:text="view1"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:text="view2"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:text="view3"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code:

**Take a look:**

> Design.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#63f542"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff00ff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the view with the code below, but the only constraint is you have to give max width to centered text view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout17"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/hint_color">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="text1"
        android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/labels_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txt2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txt2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txt2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:text="text2asdadadasdaasdasdddadadadaddadadasdasdasdasdasdasddadasdasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasddadadadadadada"
        android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/labels_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txt3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txt3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txt3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt3"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="text3"
        android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/labels_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: try to set max-width to the center textview programmatically, like 66% of the screen